# Scala - Create a new list by by concatenating elements from list 1 list 2 elements in functional style

Tags: scala

I have two lists, "firstName" and "lastName", I want to create a new list "fullName" by concatenating corresponding elements (Strings) from first list and second list as show below.

Input Lists:

```
firstName: List[String] = List("Rama","Dev")
lastName: List[String] = List("krish","pandi")
```

---

Expected output:

```
Fullname:List[String] = List("Rama krish", "Dev Pandi")
```

Could you please let me know how this can be achieved in functional style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking this step by step, the first thing to do is to `zip` the lists to get a new list of pairs:

```
scala> val firstName: List[String] = List("Rama","Dev")
firstName: List[String] = List(Rama, Dev)

scala> val lastName: List[String] = List("krish","pandi")
lastName: List[String] = List(krish, pandi)

scala> firstName.zip(lastName)
res0: List[(String, String)] = List((Rama,krish), (Dev,pandi))
```

Note that if the lists aren't the same length, the longer one will be truncated.

Next you can use `map` to take each pair and turn it into a new string:

```
scala> firstName.zip(lastName).map {
     |   case (first, last) => s"$first $last"
     | }
res1: List[String] = List(Rama krish, Dev pandi)
```

I'm using string interpolation here (the `s"$variableName"` part), but you could also just use `+` to concatenate the strings.